# android - creating a layout and setting a new ID in a fragment

Tags: android, layout

Im trying to create a new Layout programmatically and i need to put inside that view a new Fragment. So, when i create that layout(That is the one which is going to contain the fragment) i have to set an ID to reference in the .replace method of the fragmenttransaction. 
I googled and i found that there is a method that generates an id but its not working. It returns the number 1, then the number 2, etc. And then my view is not getting found. Any idea? Ignore the FOR until < 1, it's just for testing.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_holder, container, false);


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        mainVideoContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.main_video_container);
        containerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.videoFragmentContainer);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) containerLayout.getLayoutParams();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++) {
            LinearLayout newLinear = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            newLinear.setLayoutParams(params);
            newLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            int idGen = View.generateViewId();
            newLinear.setId(idGen);
            testFragment testFragment = new testFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(idGen,testFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            mainVideoContainer.addView(newLinear);
        }




        videos = new ArrayList<>();

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fix it by changing this:

```
int idGen = View.generateViewId() + 878977;
```

im sure that this is completely wrong but it works.